# Netty custom hostname verification

Tags: java, ssl, netty

I'm trying to figure out how to add a whitelist of SAN entries to my netty server that will essentially bypass hostname verification.

Right now I've the following code to enable hostname verification:

```
SSLEngine sslEngine = getSSLEngine();
SSLParameters sslParameters = sslEngine.getSSLParameters();
sslParameters.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS");
sslEngine.setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
```

Is there a method somewhere I can override when the hostname is being  verified?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using `SSLEngine` is not the same than using `SslEngine` (Netty) : they are not interchangeable. Be carefull.
Secondly, here, the hostname is not directly accessible so you can't get it so easily (as a cat who do not want to be taken by some hands).

You could use a custom proxy implementation with your whitelist to reach your goal, redirecting the flow for your hostnames chosen and kick out the hostnames you don't want to handle (all the rest).

If I were you, I will seek some existing solutions implemented, for security considerations. They are plenty of Gateways solutions but my personal preference is going to Spring Cloud Gateway. With it, it becomes easy to handle what you are trying to do :

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
        .route("route1", r -> r.host("**.site1.com")
        .and()
        .path("/path1")
        .uri("https://site1.com"))
        .route(r -> r.host("**.site1.com")
        .and()
        .path("/path2")
        .filters(f -> f.prefixPath("/prefix"))
        .uri("https://site2.com")
        .id("customID"))
    .build();
}
```